# Validator.IsValid is true even when value is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CompareValidatorInputTextBox1.IsValid && CompareValidatorInputTextBox2.IsValid) 
    {

        foo();
        blah();
    }
}
```

Hello. I am trying to take only numbers into two boxes. On the page the Validator shows up telling me that non numbers are invalid. However when I try to use the values after selecting an operation the isValid property always has true, even if the textBox validator says it's invalid. I'm new to asp.net so I'm a bit confused.

Here is one of the textboxes from my .aspx file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputTextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator 
    ID="CompareValidatorInputTextBox1" 
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="inputTextBox1"
    CausesValidation="True"
    operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Double"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Number"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ></asp:CompareValidator><br />
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to give.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to use the values after selecting an operation"?

Comment: Ah that's unclear. I'll update the text. What I mean to say is that I try to use the values in an event handler which is the top code. But when I try to use them, even if they were invalid on my .aspx page the Validator.IsValid property has true.

Comment: The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.isvalid(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation says the `Validate` method has to have been called for the `IsValid` property to be up to date.  Are you sure this has been done at the time you're checking it in teh code?

Comment: That's exactly what it was @MikeofSST thanks so much. If you want to post and answer I'll mark it completed. Or should I just mark it as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force validation call by calling validate method on each validator:

```
protected void dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CompareValidatorInputTextBox1.Validate();
    CompareValidatorInputTextBox2.Validate();
    if (CompareValidatorInputTextBox1.IsValid && CompareValidatorInputTextBox2.IsValid) 
    {
        foo();
        blah();
    }
}
```

However in my code when I tried to reproduce your problem the validator has been called. Maybe you have some validation groups set on some controls...

Comment: I don't think I have some validation groups. I'm still new to this but would that be effected by the CausesValidation="true"? 

Thanks for your answer it's the same as @MikeofSST mentioned above and it works.

Comment: Maybe you haven't set CausesValidation="true" on your drop down list. As far as I know - it can be caused by lack of this flag. However I'm not sure whether this flag is not true by default. Sometimes some things doesn't work as they should and forcing validation is not bad way to mend it.